# Leetcode question #845 Longest Mountain in Array

Tags: python, python-3.x

Here is my code:

```
    def longestMountain(self, A: List[int]) -> int:
        i=1
        list=[]
        if len(A)<3:
            return 0
        if (len(A)==3 and A[0]>=A[1] and A[1]<=A[2]):
            return 0
        while i < len(A):
            count=1
            if A[i]<=A[i-1]:
                i+=1
            while (i< len(A) and A[i]>A[i-1]):
                count+=1
                i+=1
            if count==1 or count==len(A):
                return 0
            while (i< len(A) and A[i]<A[i-1]):
                count+=1
                i+=1
            list.append(count)
        return max(list)
```

When testing the case which is A=[0,1,0,2,2], the expected result is 3 but output 0. Can someone check my code?

Here is the leetcode question:
Let's call any (contiguous) subarray B (of A) a mountain if the following properties hold:

B.length >= 3
There exists some 0 < i < B.length - 1 such that B[0] < B[1] < ... B[i-1] < B[i] > B[i+1] > ... > B[B.length - 1]
(Note that B could be any subarray of A, including the entire array A.)

Given an array A of integers, return the length of the longest mountain.

Return 0 if there is no mountain.

Example 1:

Input: [2,1,4,7,3,2,5]
Output: 5
Explanation: The largest mountain is [1,4,7,3,2] which has length 5.
Example 2:

Input: [2,2,2]
Output: 0
Explanation: There is no mountain.

Comment: The "return 0" in the while-loop returns if it finds no more mountains regardless if a previous mountain was found. In case "count == 1" it should break the loop and check for empty list separately after the loop.

Answer (score 1):

We can just count the ups and downs and use `max()`:

```
class Solution:
    def longestMountain(self, nums):
        longest = 0
        up = down = 0
        for i in range(1, len(nums)):
            if down and nums[i - 1] < nums[i] or nums[i - 1] == nums[i]:
                up = down = 0

            up += nums[i - 1] < nums[i]
            down += nums[i - 1] > nums[i]

            if up and down:
                longest = max(longest, up + down + 1)

        return longest
```